# How to SELECT last 50 entries except latest 5 from a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with around 1000 entries.

I want to `SELECT` the latest 50 of these entries except the most recent 5 ones. I know how to do this using nested query, but is there a simple way or some special keyword to do something like this.

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from your_table
order by some_column desc
limit 5, 45
```

Comment: i think it would be `limit 5,45`

Comment: No, it is `offset, number_of_records`. You want to grab 50 records, right?

Comment: I wanted to grab 45 latest records except the last 5. So I guess i asked the question wrong way. Thanks anyway